# Cannot close Window after opening another window modally

Tags: cocoa, swift3, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have a problem. 
In my mac osx app I have a mainwindow. This window is opening initial. I am working with storyboard. 
But there are moments when the user needs to login again into the app. If this is the case (for example when the session ends) I open a new small window modally with this code:

```
private func openLogin() {
    loginController = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "LoginController") as? LoginWindowController
    guard let window = loginController?.window else {
        return false
    }
    NSApp.runModal(for: window)
}
```

after I once opened this window and close it again I can never close the main window. If the login window never opened, there is no problem and I can close the MainWindow. But if I opened the loginwindow once, I cannot close the mainwindow. I can click on the close button but it does nothing.

And, I cannot assure this but, I think that I cannot close any window after that.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you for your Help!

Artur

Comment: Docs say, "You can exit the modal loop by calling the stopModal, stopModalWithCode:, or abortModal methods".  Do you do any of those things when you close the modal window?

Comment: Yes I have. Thank you for that hint. I descriped the problem in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the issue...

I called the code function `openLogin()` inside of the `windowDidLoad()` function of the `NSWindowController`. The problem is that the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of the appDelegate will first be called after the `windowDidLoad` function finished, which is logically correct.

I stopped the mainThread by running a window modally. Somehow the framework doesn´t like this before the app has completed the launch process.

I solved this by using the `NSNotificationCenter` and observe the notification name `NSApplicationDidFinishLaunching`. On that I run the `openLogin()` code.